# Isotope and DOM Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

In this CodePen ( http://codepen.io/marcamos/pen/LkZByj ) I've set up an Isotope grid of images that are either square, landscape, or portrait, where the landscapes are 2x as wide and the portraits are 2x as tall as the squares. **(Samples of the HTML, CSS, and JS in the CodePen are at the bottom of this post.)**

Regardless of viewport width, I'm seeing a blank area above that I *thought* a square would move right into. See this screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1851858/Grid_Demo.jpg

This strikes me as Isotope being limited by DOM order … which might very well be true, but I *thought* Isotope's Masonry layout would ignore such things and fill all available space. Am I wrong?

---

```
<ul class="grid" id="grid">
  <li class="grid__sizer"></li>
  <li class="grid__item grid__item--landscape fadable">
    <a href="#">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://noonsharp.design/client/tag/imgs/fpo-square/fpo-2x1.jpg" /> <!-- Landscape -->
        <figcaption class="grid__meta">
          <span class="grid__project-name">Project Title</span>
          <span class="grid__client-name">Client</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- ...and so on... -->


.grid__item--square,
.grid__item--portrait,
.grid__sizer {
  width: 50%;

  @media (min-width:$bp-medium) {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}

.grid__item--landscape {
  width: 100%;

  @media (min-width:$bp-medium) {
    width: 66.666%;
  }
}
<!-- ...and so on... -->


var grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid__item',
  percentPosition: true,
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.grid__sizer'
  }
});

grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
  grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer to my question is: use the Packery layout mode rather than Masonry, straight from Metafizzy: https://twitter.com/metafizzyco/status/758733290136178691

If you visit the CodePen url I posted above, you'll see it all works as desired now.

Thanks Metafizzy!